# Am I defining this variable incorrectly? "ReferenceError: format is not defined"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

It looks to me like I'm defining these variables correctly, but I'm getting errors for `format, filetype, filesize, height, and width`. The error is "`ReferenceError: {variable name} is not defined`". The issue doesn't happen for name and location, it only affects the variable `format` and all other variables that are declared afterwards in the `meta` object.

I'm trying to build a component and pass props. Here are the relevant pieces of code:

```
AdminGalleryTile.propTypes = {
  onPress: func,
  onSelectPress: func,
  selected: bool,
  meta: shape({
    name: string,
    location: string,
    format: string,
    filetype: string,
    filesize: number,
    height: number,
    width: number,
  }),
};

export default function AdminGalleryTile({
  onPress = () => {},
  onSelectPress = () => {},
  selected,
  style,
  source,
  meta = {name, location, format, filetype, filesize, height, width},
}) {
  return (...);}



              <AdminGalleryTile
                style={style.GalleryTile}
                source={item.uri}
                name="Do I look like I know what a jpeg is?"
                location="Hank Hill"
                format="image"
                filetype="JPG"
                filesize="420 kb"
                height="1080"
                width="1920"
                selected={selection.find((s) => s.uri === item.uri)}
                onSelectPress={() => toggleSelect(item)}
              />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `meta` object instead of using each keys of `meta`.

```html
<AdminGalleryTile
  style={style.GalleryTile}
  source={item.uri}
  meta={{
    name: 'Do I look like I know what a jpeg is?',
    location: 'Hank Hill',
    format: 'image',
    filetype: 'JPG',
    filesize: '420 kb',
    height: '1080',
    width: '1920'
  }}
  selected={selection.find((s) => s.uri === item.uri)}
  onSelectPress={() => toggleSelect(item)}
/>
```

Also, it seems like you want to spread `meta` object in `AdminGalleryTitle` function paramter. But currently, you're setting the default value to the object.

Change following line

```js
meta = {name, location, format, filetype, filesize, height, width},
```

to

```js
meta: { name, location, format, filetype, filesize, height, width }
```

Answer (score 1):

According to your types, you supposed to pass a `meta` object while you passing the props on top level:

```
<AdminGalleryTile meta={{ name, location, ... }} />
```

Comment: Yup totally missed that. Thank you for saving me from banging my head against the wall.